# BLTouch probes off the print bed

Tags: bltouch, reprap

I have just upgraded my mobo to a Duet 3 WiFi clone (FLY-RRF-E3) and installed a BLTouch. When I try to run true bed leveling the Touch probes off of the bed like in the Reddit post ["Ender 3 bltouch probes off the bed. Anyone know what to change in the firmware to fix this?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/jim123/ender_3_bltouch_probes_off_the_bed_anyone_know/) I have tried to change the X and Y offsets with `M851` as described in the link, but the RepRap firmware does not respect the changes. Then, I read in the [Duet3D Documentation](https://docs.duet3d.com/User_manual/Reference/Gcodes):

> Innn   Parameter - X-offset in arc move (Not yet implemented in RepRapFirmware); integral (Ki) in PID Tuning; signal inversion
>
> Jnnn   Parameter - Y-offset in arc move (Not yet implemented in RepRapFirmware)

Finally, I read that there is a `G31` command which is similar to the `M851` command, so I tried that. Still, no dice. Here is what I currently have in the Z-probe section of my `config.h` file.

```
;M558 P0 H6 F120 T8000                ; disable Z probe but set dive height, probe speed and travel speed
;G31 X0 Y0 Z0                         ; no probe offsets
;BL Touch Z-Probe settings
M558 P9 H6 F250:30 T8000 C"^probe"    ; set Z probe type to bltouch and the dive height + speeds
G31 X-41.0 Y-5.0 Z0                   ; no probe offsets
M950 S0 C"Servo0"                     ; Setup Servo0 as servo port on Fly-E3
;bltouch offset
;M851 X-41 Y-5
```

Firmware: RepRapFirmware for STM32F4 based Boards 3.4.0_1 (2022-03-17)

Note: Initially, I installed my BLTouch incorrectly because it has different wire colors.
P.S. My glass bed is true, so if a possible solution is too costly then it wouldn't be worthwhile. Thanks for reading.